# Any way to speed up instaparse?

Tags: clojure, instaparse

I'm trying to use instaparse on a dimacs file less than 700k in size, with the following grammar

```
<file>=<comment*> <problem?> clause+
comment=#'c.*'
problem=#'p\s+cnf\s+\d+\s+\d+\s*'
clause=literal* <'0'>
<literal>=#'[1-9]\d*'|#'-\d+'
```

calling like so

```
(def parser
  (insta/parser (clojure.java.io/resource "dimacs.bnf") :auto-whitespace :standard))
...
(time (parser (slurp filename)))
```

and it's taking about a hundred seconds. That's three orders of magnitude slower than I was hoping for. Is there some way to speed it up, some way to tweak the grammar or some option I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar is wrong. It can't be satisfied.

- Every `file` ends with a `clause`.
- Every `clause` ends with a `'0'`.
- The `literal` in the `clause`, being a [greedy reg-exp](https://github.com/engelberg/instaparse#regular-expressions-a-word-of-warning),will eat
  the final `'0'`.

Conclusion: No `clause` will ever be found.

For example ...

```
=> (parser "60")
Parse error at line 1, column 3:
60
  ^
Expected one of:
"0"
#"\s+"
#"-\d+"
#"[1-9]\d*"
```

We can parse a `literal`

```
=> (parser "60" :start :literal)
("60")
```

... but not a `clause`

```
=> (parser "60" :start :clause)
Parse error at line 1, column 3:
60
  ^
Expected one of:
"0" (followed by end-of-string)
#"\s+"
#"-\d+"
#"[1-9]\d*"
```

---

*Why is it so slow?*

If there is a `comment`:

- it can swallow the whole file;
- or be broken at any `'c'` character into successive `comment`s;
- or terminate *at any point after the initial `'c'`*.

This implies that every tail has to be presented to the rest of the grammar, which includes a reg-exp for `literal` that Instaparse can't see inside. Hence all have to be tried, and all will ultimately fail. No wonder it's slow.

---

I suspect that this file is actually divided into *lines*. And that your problems arise from trying to conflate newlines with other forms of white-space.

May I gently point out that playing with a few tiny examples - which is all I've done - might have saved you a deal of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your extensive use of * is causing the problem. Your grammar is too ambiguous/ambitious (I guess). I would check two things:

```
;;run it as
 (insta/parses grammar input)
;; with a small input
```

That will show you how much ambiguity is in your grammar definition: [check](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) "ambiguous grammar".

Read Engelberg [performance notes](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse/blob/master/docs/Performance.md), it would help understand your own problem and probably find out what fits best for you.